# Strange redirect to https://www.example.com/cs_CZ

Tags: .htaccess

I use this tuned htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^\.htaccess/?$ - [NC,F]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} =""
RewriteRule ^.*$ /public/index.php [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/public/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /public/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^public/.*$ /public/index.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

When I try a url that demonstrably does not exist, e.g. https://www.example.com/aaa, it redirect to https://www.example.com/cs_CZ and ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS error. In application is not such redirect. Could be cause it by some rule of htaccess?

In addition to redirecting to the https and www versions of the website, htaccess points from the root of the website to the public folder, where the index.php file is.

Comment: `/cs_CZ` sounds like a locale getting appended (Czech/CZECHIA)? Can’t see _that_ coming from the .htaccess you have shown, and it sounds more like something the application itself would be in charge of.

Comment: Yes it is, but I cannot find any such redirect in app

Comment: What exactly did you look for? You should probably not expect to find `https://www.example.com/cs_CZ` anywhere directly in the source code, rather likely this is dynamically assembled based on the base address and default language or locale (that is Czech in your app, correct?)

Comment: With `cs_CZ` not contained anywhere in your above .htaccess code, really the only way it could come from there, is if it was taken from either the original request itself (but `https://www.example.com/aaa` did not contain `cs_CZ` anywhere), or some environment variable, but I don’t see the code explicitly accessing any of those either.

Comment: You're probably right. The fact is that there is no redirection in the application. I was not looking for the string directly, but the occurrence of cs_CZ and there is nothing like that anywhere.